# Firebase Cloud Function Terminating before Database Data Downloaded

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying operate on all children in a Firebase Realtime Database directory, however, I am running into a problem that I cannot solve. Using the "child_added" trigger to download the data calls the function for every child in the directory. Normally using promises in this kind of situation would be fine, however, because the same function is called multiple times my function ends up continuing after the on('child_added') function is called once and missing all the other calls. I have no idea how to remedy this, all suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `child_added`, because it never stops listening, and your function must terminate as soon as possible.  Instead, use `once('value')` to fetch all the data, and make use of its returned promise to continue when its snapshot is available.  It might be similar to [this sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/limit-children), in addition to many others in that repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use promises, but instead of closing the function after one promise is returned wait for all promises.

I'm not sure what your Cloud Function looks like, but let's assume it's a database trigger

```
functions.database.ref('/some/trigger').onWrite(async event => {
  const promises = [];
  admin.database().ref('/some_child').on('child_added', snapshot => {
    const pushRef = admin.database().ref('/some_path').push(snapshot.val()); // Some pretend async operation

    promises.push(pushRef);
  });

  return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

In this example I'm listening to `/some/trigger` then getting all the children at the path `/some_child`.

I'll then save each child into a new object under `/some_path`.

Each promise is pushed into an array and the `Promise.all` will cause the function to wait for all promises (writes) to resolve.

Comment: I think you also need to push the child_added async operation